# DBT grants feature

Tags: dbt

We would like to use the dbt grants feature in our project.
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-configs

Earlier, the permissions were passed as below:

```
on-run-start:
  - "{{ create_role__create_procedure('Role1') }}"
  - "{{ create_role__create_procedure('Role2') }}"

on-run-end:
  - "{{ grant_select_on_schemas(['Schema1'], 'role1') }}"
  - GRANT ROLE Role1 to ROLE Role2;
```

Can I get equivalent for the same in grants feature mentioned above link

Answer (score 0):

The new `grants` config introduced in v1.2 only applies to the Relation that is materialized by each model (so, a specific table or view).

Typically you would use a model post-hook to grant select on a table right after it was created:

```
{{ config(post_hook="grant select on {{ this }} to reporter") }}
```

This can be replaced with:

```
{{ config(grants={"select": ["reporter"]}) }}
```

But it looks like that's not how you have been configuring your grants. The [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/grants) make it clear that as of now (v1.3), you will still need to use hooks if you want to:

> Apply grants on other database objects besides views and tables.

So you'll have to stick with your current scheme, or refactor to use table-level grants.